# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped detecting wifi networks after installing pppoe

Tags: wireless

I upgraded from 14.04 to 18.04.  Initially, my wifi was working fine, networks were being detected and I could connect to them.

However, this stopped working when I installed `pppoe` and the DSL provider plugin.  After that, I stopped being able to detect wifi networks and can't get wifi connections.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why did you install `pppoe`?  If Wifi was working as normal, you likely didn't need to install PPPoE software.

Comment: Actually I created two DSL/PPPOE connections one for VPN and one for Internet.To start/stop these two there is no shortcut on top bar.So just to do pon and poff I installed pppoe. That was mistake as my wifi now stopped. I did apt autoremove pppoe.so but problem not solved.

Comment: Any solution after grammatical corrections?

Comment: Wasting time for last four days